# text inside table jups to new line when i resize window

Tags: html, css

I have table with 4 columns and 1 row width set to 100% in css.

When i re-size window from screen to smaller text from last cell jumps to new line. and if i change zoom in browser "Ctrl+mouse wheel up" when text reaches edge of window it jumps to next line.

I noticed if i set table width to 1000px and resize window text stays on same line just fine.

But i have to have table 100% width as i use it as header with background that stretch over page. I wonder is there CSS code to stop text jumping on window resize?

```
<table width="100%" height="48px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="auto" style="background-image: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/webmasters/img/bg-header.png); background-repeat: repeat-x;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="1000px" style="background-image: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/webmasters/img/bg-header.png); padding-top: 2px; overflow:hidden;">

                    <div class="inline login_box1" style="margin-left:112px;">
                        <input type="text" name="user_login" value="Username" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline login_box2" style="margin-left:26px;">
                        <input type="text" name="user_password_text" ialue="Password" />


                    </div>
                    <div class="inline login_box1" style="margin-left:50px;">
                        <input type="text" name="employer_login" value="Username"  />
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline login_box2" style="margin-left:26px;">
                        <input type="text" name="employer_password_text"  value="Password"  />


                    </div>
        </td>

        <td width="auto" style="background-image: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/webmasters/img/bg-header.png); background-repeat: repeat-x;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is broken thing http://jsfiddle.net/LzTfF/2 when you Ctrl + mouse wheel up you zoom out and see all boxes on same line when you Ctrl + mouse wheel down you zoom it and see boxes jump to next line

Now this one http://jsfiddle.net/9eYZx/1 i changed in first line table width to 1000px instead of 100% and now it works fine when you zoom - input boxes go behind window instead of jumping down to next line. however i need blue background to be stretched 100% over the page horizontally and setting fixed width does not do it. If i say set width to 2000px it will create horizontal scroll bar in browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you could do. The easiest would be wrapping your elements up and then give that wrapper a fixed width, this way the children within the wrapper won't be affected by the screen size. you could also re-assign widths using media queries.

```
<table id="table" >
<tr>
  <td class="auto_td" >&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="monkey_td">
    <div id="anchor">
      <div class="inline login_box1">
        <input type="text" name="user_login" value="Username" />
      </div>

      <div class="inline login_box2">
        <input type="text" name="user_password_text" ialue="Password" />
      </div>

      <div class="inline login_box1">
        <input type="text" name="employer_login" value="Username"  />
      </div>

      <div class="inline login_box2">
        <input type="text" name="employer_password_text"  value="Password"  />
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="auto_td" >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

*Note*: you should remove as much inline css from your html as possible. its going to get messy and hard to follow whats going on

```
.monkey_td{
  width: 1000px;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/webmasters/img/bg-header.png);
  padding-top: 2px; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
.auto_td {
  width: auto;
  background-image: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/webmasters/img/bg-header.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#table {
  width:100%;
  height:48px;
  border: none;
  /* getts rid of cellpadding html attr and cellspacing html attr */
  border-spacing:0; 
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

/*this is the anchor that will keep her children from wondering when screen sizes change*/
#anchor {
  width:800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inline {
  display:inline;
  margin-left:0 auto;
}
```

hope that helps :)

Comment: I cannot set fixed width as i need background to be stretched horizontally over screen.

Comment: Seems making table align center and width 1000px then wrapping it in div with background i want to stretch around table works great and more simple.